# Calling pyqt windows

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I created 2 windows on QT4. 
In Idle i managed to show Window 1 and adding a closing action once button is clicked.
I would like to call and display window 2 by clicking this button. My code is:

```
import os

import shlex

import sys, Tkinter

#import Converted Python UI File

from W0 import Ui_MainWindow1
```

If i include `from W import Ui_MainWindow2` for calling my 2nd windows, it shows directly my window2 and skip window 1!!

```
class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Button close the window1(would like to show window 2 instead now) .
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()
```

Comment: First, why are you importing `Tkinter` into a `Qt` program? Second, please fix the indentation; it's very hard to guess what you're doing wrong when the code isn't runnable or readable.

Comment: Also, you haven't shown us enough code. your `Main.__init__` instantiates some class `Ui_MainWindow`, but there's no code that creates such a class. You're doing `from W0 import Ui_MainWindow1`, but what you might consider a minor typo, the interpreter will consider a completely different thing, and give you a `NameError`.

Comment: Finally, it seems pretty likely that the problem with your actual code is either (a) you're trying to put `W0.Ui_MainWindow1` and `W1.Ui_MainWindow2` into the same variable, or (b) you've got some setup code in `W0` or `W1` that's running its own event loop, so the one in your main script never even gets to run. Without seeing your actual running code, including `W0.py` and `W1.py`—or, better, a stripped-down version of it that's just big enough to demonstrate the problem—it's going to be hard to do more than guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from W0 import Ui_MainWindow1
from W import Ui_MainWindow2

class Main1(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow1()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

class Main2(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow2()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window1 = Main1()
    window1.show()

    window2 = Main2()
    window2.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()
```